# fetching null value from sqlite3 show in view

Tags: iphone, sqlite

i m working on a project in which i have a data base sqlite 3 in which i have 3 colum for text and i am fetching the values and showing them into a view ie;
text6 fields.but in my code there is a condition that user can fill any one text field of three and two can be blank but when i am fetching the values the two text field shows (null) instead of blank value how can i resolve this problem so that after fetching the data it will show blank not null
here is my code for inserting the data

```
    - (void)saveData
    {
        if ((txtfield.text.length==0)||(txtfield1.text.length==0)||(txtfield2.text.length==0)||(txtfield3.text.length==0)||(txtfield4.text.length==0))

            {  
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"fields can't be blank"
                                                     message:@"fill the fields"
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];

                 [alert show];
               [alert release];
            }
            else{

                NSString* gratitude2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtfield3.text];
                NSString* gratitude1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtfield4.text];
                NSString* title = txtfield.text;
                NSString* date = txtfield1.text;
                NSString* gratitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtfield2.text];

            [dbSingleton() createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
            [dbSingleton() insertdata:gratitude2 withgratitude1:gratitude1 title:title date:date gratitude:gratitude picture:imageDt audio:self.retrieveData];
            }
```

and here is to display it on view on iphone

```
            -(void)gototree:(UIButton *)sender
            {

                int tag1=sender.tag;
                 [dbSingleton() createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
                  NSMutableArray * array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
              array =[dbSingleton() getalldata:tag1];

                NSString *gratitude22=[[array objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"gratitude2"];
                NSString *gratitude11=[[array objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"gratitude1"];
                NSString *title11 = [[array objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"title"];
                NSString *date11=[[array objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"Date"];
                NSString *gratitude=[[array objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"gratitude"];


               txtfield2=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(28, 164, 200,20)];
               txtfield2.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

                txtfield2.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13.0];
                [self.view addSubview:txtfield2];
                 [txtfield2 setEnabled:NO];

                txtfield2.text=gratitude;

                txtfield3=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(28, 183, 200,20)];
                txtfield3.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

                txtfield3.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13.0];
                [self.view addSubview:txtfield3];
                 [txtfield3 setEnabled:NO];
                txtfield3.text=gratitude22;


              txtfield4=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(28, 204, 200,20)];
                txtfield4.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

                txtfield4.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13.0];
                [self.view addSubview:txtfield4];

                 [txtfield4 setEnabled:NO];
                txtfield4.text=gratitude11;
            }
```

Comment: Rollback since edit screwed up the indention even worse. The edit approval system doesn't display code in the same way as it appears here...

Comment: Why some usual *txtfieldN.text ? txtfieldN.text : @"";* is bad?